# Linux dump file - can it be read on Windows system?

Tags: linux, windows, mount, dump

Is there a way to mount/read linux file created with `/sbin/dump` under Windows system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile dump on windows using mingw ( heck, it might even already be done for you in msys ), and use restore to read it just like you would on linux.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different projects which do just that. The following should get you started in the right direction - http://www.fs-driver.org/.